# Object with Only Id

Tags: nhibernate

I want to get an object from my database but only populate it with the unique id identifier. I want all other fields to be null...any ideas on how to approach this????

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL?  Entities Framework?  ADO.NET?

Comment: Entities framework - NHibernate.

Comment: Entity Framework and NHibernate are two entirely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NHibernate Linq` provider:

```
Person obj = session.Query<Person>()
                    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                    .Select(x => new Person() { Id = x.Id } )
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: It will fetch only one object. If more than one object result from the query, it will throw an exception.

Comment: You said get "AN" object as in one object.  SingleOrDefault() does this.

Comment: yes I did say AN object - but what I want is just the object with its ID. I do not want a populated object..are u saying this command will give me this???